Deleting overlapping instances on points in Geonodes (Blender 4.2)
I've been trying, and failing, for several days to figure out how to delete overlapping instances-on-points from two separate sources, using Blender 4.2. I've tried the usual solutions of Raycasting (using the larger cubes as the target; see below) and Geometry Proximity nodes and nothing seems to work. The problem is that the two different types of objects perfectly overlap with each other; one is a set of 2x2m cubes and the other is a set of 2x4m cubes:

Each type of cube (5 small, 2 large) are in their own collection and were instanced on points on a grid:

You can see where the Z-fighting is taking place, where the 2x4 and 2x2 cubes perfectly overlap each other. I want to get rid of the 2x2 cubes where they overlap the 2x4 cubes. Raycasting doesn't seem to work; realizing the instances of the 2x4 cubes and plugging them into Raycasting doesn't do anything at all. Geometry Proximity just seems to take out all the small cubes, rather than those just overlapping the big ones.
My geonodes setup is here:

How do I accomplish this?

Beware, if you use axis-aligned cuboids as an example,  you're likely to get an answer that doesn't work for arbitrary shapes

For axis-aligned and grid-aligned voxels, you may want to just check neighbors: how can I make instances responsible to each-other - so if there's no "tall" neighbor at immediate bottom, or "wide" at immediate left, or "big" ("tall"+"wide") at immediate bottom-left, then you can spawn 1x1 cube. If there's no immediate top-left "wide" neighbor you can spawn "tall" cuboid (1x2). If there's no immediate bottom-right "tall" neighbor, you can spawn "wide" cuboid (2x1), and if you can spawn both "tall" and "wide", then you can also spawn "big" 2x2

Now the problem is, being "tall" or not depends on the neighbor being tall or not. And the neighbor also depends and so on. So you need a serial algorithm, like the one I implement here (actually seemingly a duplicate): Stack instances randomly into grid but respect their dimensions (huge wall of drawers)

Thank you! Looks like I faceplanted pretty hard. I figured the answer would be intermediate level, but I leapfrogged straight to "advanced." Building a diode logic tree in geonodes was way more than I thought would be necessary.
Thank you, Markus! This was quite an education in geonodes!

If you want to specifially just merge points of a line in pairs, that can be done with a very simple algorithm.

In truth this was a Ducky3D exercise that I was trying to take to the next level. He used a single size of cube in different colors, instanced to Distribute Points to Volume (with the volume being a 10x10x40 cube). But one of the examples he gave as inspiration used three sizes, 2x2, 2x1, 1x1. I figured it wouldn't take that much to create a 2x1 and 1x1 matrix, but hoo boy...did I get in over my head in a hurry. Thanks again!

To not be guilty of demotivating you from learning geonodes by linking

 how can I make instances responsible to each-other 
 Stack instances randomly into grid but respect their dimensions (huge wall of drawers) 

Here's a simple solution:

Imgur mirror (SE image hosting has problems)
The idea is simple, prepare all possible arrangements of a cell (I prepared just two but hopefully it's obvious how to extend the setup) and populate cells with randomly picked arrangements:

Imgur mirror
Notice the red arrows - they point at continuous spacing which is the result of the simplicity of the algorithm and the reason why I had to use a complicated algorithm to nicely randomize varying sized blocks.

This is fantastic. The more complex answers didn't demotivate me at all; more there was a huge gap in my more basic Ducky3D-level knowledge, and the advanced logic setups you pointed to. It's good to print those out, and just study them to see how it fits together.
What I ultimately need is an intermediate and advanced Geonodes course to really get deep into it, once I learn the basics. If you have any suggestions for heavy geonodes courses, I am all ears!
